# spring inject enum Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.alibaba.asyncload.AsyncLoadExecutor$HandleMode]

Tags: java, spring, enums

I am use alibaba asyncload (https://github.com/alibaba/asyncload)
implement the async features ,but get some error while inject the enum value to the bean property by spring when lanch my webapp。

Strangely
while i lanch app from local machine by eclipse.
when config is config1,the app is lanch success with no problem.

config1:

```
<bean id="asyncLoadExecutor" class="com.alibaba.asyncload.AsyncLoadExecutor" init-method="initital" destroy-method="destory">
    <property name="poolSize" value="10"/>
    <property name="acceptCount" value="100"/>
    <property name="mode" ref="mode"/>
</bean>
<bean id="mode" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.FieldRetrievingFactoryBean">
    <property name="staticField" value="com.alibaba.asyncload.AsyncLoadExecutor.HandleMode.CALLERRUN" />
</bean>
```

but if the config change to config2,

config2:

```
<bean id="asyncLoadExecutor" class="com.alibaba.asyncload.AsyncLoadExecutor" init-method="initital" destroy-method="destory">
    <property name="poolSize" value="10"/>
    <property name="acceptCount" value="100"/>
    <property name="mode" value="CALLERRUN"/>
</bean>
```

the lanch get the error message

> 严重: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class cn.dbn.sysmodule.staticspringcontext.StaticSpringContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'asyncLoadExecutor' defined in class path resource [service-asyncload.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.alibaba.asyncload.AsyncLoadExecutor$HandleMode' for property 'mode'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.alibaba.asyncload.AsyncLoadExecutor$HandleMode] for property 'mode': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
>       at cn.dbn.sysmodule.staticspringcontext.StaticSpringContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(StaticSpringContextLoaderListener.java:14)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.alibaba.asyncload.AsyncLoadExecutor$HandleMode' for property 'mode'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.alibaba.asyncload.AsyncLoadExecutor$HandleMode] for property 'mode': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:463)
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:494)
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:488)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1463)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>       ... 21 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.alibaba.asyncload.AsyncLoadExecutor$HandleMode] for property 'mode': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
>       at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:267)
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:448)
>       ... 27 more

while i lanch app by server machine by Tomcat container.
when config is config1,the app lance get the follow error message

> [ERROR] 2016-11-26 11:34:37,896 [localhost-startStop-1] web.context.ContextLoader       org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:215) -Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'asyncLoadExecutor' defined in class path resource [service-asyncload.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.alibaba.asyncload.AsyncLoadExecutor$HandleMode' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'mode'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.alibaba.asyncload.AsyncLoadExecutor$HandleMode] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'mode': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
>           at cn.dbn.sysmodule.staticspringcontext.StaticSpringContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(StaticSpringContextLoaderListener.java:14)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5099)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5615)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.alibaba.asyncload.AsyncLoadExecutor$HandleMode' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'mode'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.alibaba.asyncload.AsyncLoadExecutor$HandleMode] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'mode': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
>           at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:463)
>           at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:494)
>           at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:488)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1463)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>           ... 21 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.alibaba.asyncload.AsyncLoadExecutor$HandleMode] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'mode': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
>           at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:267)
>           at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:448)
>           ... 27 more
>   Nov 26, 2016 11:34:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal

but config2 is all success with no problem.

how to inject the enum value to the bean property, use enum string or FieldRetrievingFactoryBean,why related to the different Environment.

I am puzzled why the asyncLoadExecutor bean to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'mode' at server machine， but  required type 'com.alibaba.asyncload.AsyncLoadExecutor$HandleMode' for property 'mode';
at local machine run with eclipse
waiting to help.

Comment: My advice would be to switch to Java config instead of XML config. Note that this AsyncLoadExecutor has a serious design problem: its public constructor and method expects a HandleMode as argument, but the HandleMode enum is package private, and thus inaccessible. Not to mention the methor named `destory` instead of `destroy`.

Comment: Class have  the private property  and public method that have no problem ,ensure the method is accessible whill be ok。

Comment: The second configuration is the correct one in terms of spring configuration syntax.

Comment: but it's run with error in local mechine,the error message is           "required type 'com.alibaba.asyncload.AsyncLoadExecutor$HandleMode' for property 'mode'  "